# Is there a function over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that is never linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime.  I wonder if there is a function $f$ that satisfies the following rule:

Whenever
$$z_1 + \dots + z_c \equiv cx \mod p$$
(where $1 < c < p$, and $z_j, x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$)

Then:
$$f(z_1) + \dots + f(z_c) \not \equiv cf(x) \mod p$$

Does such a function exist?

Comment: That's quite convoluted. Why not make the definition of a "never linear" function $f:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ just
$$f(x_1)+f(x_2)\neq f(x_1+x_2)\text{ for all }x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it, it is not possible.

Consider any function $f$ on $\mathbb Z_p$, and let $f(0) = n$ ($0 \le n < p$). Now $\underbrace{0 + 0 + \cdots + 0}_c = c \times 0$, and $\underbrace{f(0) + f(0) + \cdots + f(0)}_c = cn = cf(0)$.

Your definition does not seem like the usual definition of linearity anyway. If it's really linearity you want, I think you should go with Zev Chonoles's definition.